# How to initialize and fill Apache Ignite database by first node?

Tags: java, database, performance, ignite, failover

I would like to use Apache Ignite as failover read-only storage so my application will be able to access the most sensitive data if main storage (Oracle) is down.

So I need to

- Start nodes
- Create schema (execute DDL queries)
- Load data from Oracle to Ignite

Seems like it's not the same as [database caching](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/caching/database-caching.html) and I don't need to use Cache. However, [this page](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading) says that I need to implement a store to load a large amount of data from 3rd parties.

So, my questions are:

1. How to effectively transfer data from Oracle to Ignite? [Data Streamers](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-streamers)?
2. Who should init this transfer? First started node? How to do that? (tutorials explain how to achieve that via clients, should I follow this advice?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think, use of a cache store without read/write-through would be a suitable option here. You can configure a [CacheJdbcPojoStore](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPojoStore.html), for example, and call [IgniteCache#loadCache(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#loadCache(org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate,%20java.lang.Object...)) on your cache, once the cluster is up. More on this topic: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store

If you don't want to use a cache store, then [IgniteDataStreamer](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteDataStreamer.html) could be a good choice. This is the fastest way to upload big amount of data to the cluster. Data loading is usually performed from a [client node](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/clients-vs-servers), when all server nodes are up and running.